# ModuleNotFoundError in Python3.6 Mac OS

Tags: python, macos

I'm getting the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml' while trying run a python script in Mac os.

I've installed python in /usr/local/bin. All the libraries are also successfully installed.

I tried setting the PATH to include the location where the libraries are installed, but it didn't help. Please advise.

Comment: Have you installed the `lxml` module using **pip** or by other means?

Comment: This is fixed by setting the PYTHONPATH variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by setting the PYTHONPATH Variable in OS X.

Comment: Setting it to what?